# Extend Forms with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, forms, extend

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html

I was reading through the site as mentioned above and tried to implement it in my project. But it just doesn't work when i click on "get me more fields" button. Here is the code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Test Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var counter = 0;

            function moreFields() {
                counter++;
                var newFields = document.getElementById("readroot").cloneNode(true);
                newFields.id = '';
                newFields.style.display = 'block';
                var newField = newFields.childNodes;
                for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
                    var theName = newField[i].name;
                    if (theName)
                        newField[i].name = theName + counter;
                }
                var insertHere = document.getElementById("writeroot");
                insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
            }

            window.onload = moreFields;


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="readroot" style="display: none">

            <input type="button" value="Remove review"
                   onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />

            <input name="cd" value="title" />

            <select name="rankingsel">
                <option>Rating</option>
                <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
                <option value="good">Good</option>
                <option value="ok">OK</option>
                <option value="poor">Poor</option>
                <option value="bad">Bad</option>
            </select><br /><br />

            <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="review">Short review</textarea>


        </div>

        <form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/show_params.cgi">

            <span id="writeroot"></span>

            <input type="button" id="moreFields" value="Give me more fields!" />
            <input type="submit" value="Send form" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry to have to ask, but how do you read the variables from the created form?

At the end you have vaible1,variable2,variabl3.... how do you read them and pass them to SQL?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it. Under the button code, I added `onclick="moreFields()"` and deleted the `id` and voila!  It works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Add onclick="moreFields()" and Delete the Button ID.

It will work fine.

Comment: Sorry, there is no value in just repeating what someone already said (in almost the same words) 4.5 years ago.